# Получить все таймеры

Tags: windows, kernel, драйвер

Делаю домашнюю работу (честно признаюсь:)), нужно просканировать все таймеры и кое-чего в них посмотреть, но завис на задаче, как их всех получить. Читал MSDN, но он даже с реальным DKK (по наполнению) расходится, к сожалению. Подскажите, кто в теме, как или хотя бы в какую сторону копать?

Comment: All your timer are belong to us!

Comment: А вообще, покажите, что уже сделали. )

Comment: Да, в общем-то, ничего: Написал стандартную DriverEntry, дальше пока затык (потому что уже надо писать то, что у меня не получается)

Comment: Всем спасибо, кто, может быть, потратил время на задачу, все получилось.